# How to make fields unique in C# using EF Core?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, entity-framework-core, dbcontext

I want to make a field unique in EF Core and I'm using .NET 5. I can't use the `[Index(IsUnique = true)]` attribute because if I try, I get an error. Maybe It's a part of EF but not EF Core.

How can I achieve this?

I've done several searches but I didn't find any suitable answer.

Comment: ``Unique Index`` is the best way, unless you check database before add new record

Comment: *I get an error.* Which error?

Comment: Not my DV. It exists in EF core 5: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.indexattribute.isunique?view=efcore-5.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do like this.

```
class MyContext: DbContext {
  public DbSet < Test > Tests;

  protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder) {
    modelBuilder.Entity < Test > ()
      .Index(x => x.ColumnName)
      .Unique();
  }
}
```

Comment: The OP knows how to apply the unique index through data annotations. You're just giving an alternative by using fluent configurations but the error will still be there. The correct answer is the one Amir gave.

Comment: Pleasure, please check the answer posted by @Amir also

Comment: Data annoations don't have any attribute to set a column as Unique. You can do that only using the fluent APIs. This answer is correct

Answer (score 1):

This usually happens when, the table has two or more records with same value of desired property.

Make them unique by deleting or editing records.

Comment: I didn't get your answer. At all.

Comment: Nope. I just copied his code block, pasted it in the DB context class, and replaced the `Test` class with my class name and It worked.